# String function php

Tags: php, string, function

I get a string like `0699245221` and i want this result `06-99-24-52-21`, do you know the best solution for this ? (Forget loop, or other, i'm sure php have got this "function".

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $string  = '0699245221';
 $modified_string = wordwrap($string, 2, '-', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.wordwrap.php

```
$str = "0699245221";
$str = wordwrap($str, 2, '-', true);
```

output: 06-99-24-52-21

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$str  = '0699245221';
echo $res  = implode("-",str_split($str, 2));
```

OR

```
$str  = '0699245221';
echo $res  = chunk_split ($str, 2, '-');
```

Second one has one issue that it adds a `-` at the end

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
    $value  = '0699245221';
    echo $res  = implode("-",str_split($value, 2));
?>
```

**Output**

```
06-99-24-52-21
```

Comment: this outputs `06-99-24-52-21-`

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. You could use something like this:

```
function addDashes($str) {
    $str = str_split($str, 2);
    $str = implode("-", $str);
    return $str;
}
```

or this:

```
function addDashes($str) {
    $str = chunk_split($string, 2, "-");
    $str = substr($str, 0, -1);
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: Whats with the downvote? It works exactly as the question asks it to.

Comment: but there are native functions to do it in one step with wordwrap(), that's why they downvoted you xD

Comment: But that is intended for wrapping text, not inserting characters into a string.

Comment: Have you even looked at the function before replying? wordwrap() does exactly what your function does but in a single step...

Comment: Yes I did. It isn't however intended for that purpose. Notice it says break not string. It is only meant to add in line breaks not characters.

Comment: Just copy paste and try the solution I provided above xD, as you see the only answers with upvotes are using wordwrap.

Comment: I know it works BUT IT IS NOT CORRECT. How hard is it for you to understand.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26533/discussion-between-aleation-and-jimjimmy1995)

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 I think you should change this line `$str = str_split($str);` to `$str = str_split($str, 2);`

Answer (score 0):

This is perfect solution tried and he give you the result like this 06-99-24-52-21

```
<?php
$str = "0699245221";
$str1= chunk_split($str,2,"-");
$str1=rtrim($str1,"-");
echo $str1;
?>
```